# How do you do OOP in Simulink (with Embedded Coder)?

Tags: oop, simulink

I'm using Simulink to develop software for an embedded device. My workflow is:

- Use Simulink models to implement business logic
- Generate C code from models using Embedded Coder
- Merge the generated C code with handwritten driver code, and compile them together

I find OO really helpful in software design. By OO I mean combining data with method.

In C, I know I can use struct to contain data, and use function with struct pointer argument to be the method. How to do that (right) in Simulink?

Answer (score 0):

By now I've got some idea to do OOP in Simulink. But it isn't good enough.

The solution is Bus + Data Store Memory + Subsystem (Reference).

Bus is used to combine primitives together, like struct in C. Data Store Memory is the object, like struct variable in C. Subsystem is the method, which takes a bus signal as input, if the method modifies the object, the subsystem also outputs a bus signal.

The problem is, subsystem cannot be used in Stateflow. Also Simulink doesn't perform enough optimization when generating C code. Even if the input and output bus signals are the same data store memory (a class method which modifies the object), Simulink will create 2 arguments in the generated function, one for input bus, one for output bus. It uses a temporary variable to hold the subsystem output bus signal, and assign the temporary to the data store memory variable after calling the function. If the subsystem is inlined, that temporary variable can be avoided, but every place the subsystem is used, there will be another copy of that function body.

If the method doesn't modify the bus signal, then Simulink Function can be used as the method, and Simulink Function is allowed in Stateflow. But if the method modifies the bus signal, then the Simulink Function needs to output a bus signal, which is not fully supported by Simulink (from the technical support), and I've met the situation when Simulink fails to generate code.